# Problem with communication between web app and ActiveMQ Artemis through VM protocol

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a docker container where I deploy a web application and a ActiveMQ Artemis broker as war files on a single Jetty instance. Communication via TCP is working like expected but through VM protocol nothing happens.
Are the applications separated in some way?

`broker.xml`:

```xml
        <connectors>
            <connector name="in-vm-connector">vm://0</connector>
            <connector name="connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
        </connectors>

        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="in-vm-acceptor">vm://0</acceptor>
            <acceptor name="acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
```

Edit:

`Creating the broker`

```java
public class EmbeddedBroker implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        SecurityConfiguration securityConfig = new SecurityConfiguration();
        securityConfig.addUser("guest", "guest");
        securityConfig.addRole("guest", "guest");
        securityConfig.setDefaultUser("guest");
        ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager securityManager = new ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager(InVMLoginModule.class.getName(), securityConfig);

        // Step 2. Create and start embedded broker.
        try {
            ActiveMQServer server = ActiveMQServers.newActiveMQServer("broker.xml", null, securityManager);
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

`Creating a connection with the broker`

```java
    @Bean
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory(@Value("${" + BROKER_URL + "}") String brokerUrl,
                                                        @Value("${" + BROKER_USERNAME + "}") String username,
                                                        @Value("${" + BROKER_PASSWORD + "}") String password) {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl, username, password);
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListener messageListener(RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        return new JmsChannel(requestHandler);
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                             MessageListener messageListener,
                                                             @Value("${" + CONSUMER_QUEUE + "}") String consumerQueueName) {
        var listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        listenerContainer.setDestinationName(consumerQueueName);
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return listenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        var jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(10000);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? What is using the `in-vm-connector`?

Comment: I made a servlet that starts the embedded broker and I want to establish a connection through VM with it. Web app and broker are different war files. TCP entry it's just for a test to check if it is working.

Comment: Can you paste your code that's creating the broker as well as the code trying to create the connection?

Comment: What client library are you using? What `BROKER_URL` are you using? Do you see any exceptions or WARN or ERROR messages in the log?

Comment: I am using artemis-spring-integration with version 2.10.1. Broker URL has value "vm://0". About the logs, I am not getting any. Normally through TCP, I see in logs that my application is creating a connection (createCoreSession, createQueue)

Comment: Do you have a Maven project you can upload somewhere (e.g. GitHub) that I can use to reproduce what you're seeing? Also, could you try the [latest release](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) of ActiveMQ Artemis? Version 2.10.1 is well over a year old at this point and hundreds of bugs have been fixed since its release.